# Proper word for "understood"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, synonyms

I want to communicate to a person that her situation and conditions are understandable and I get it.

Is:

> You're being **understood**.

the most accurate one? Is "understood" the best word in this context?

Comment: Can you say a bit more about what "her situation" is? A better term might be context dependant.

Comment: How about "That's understandable", or "I understand you"?

Comment: _"I understand"_ and _"I get what you're saying"_ are both valid options; I don't know that one is "more accurate" than the other. I also don't think you'll find a "best word"; as @user3169 says, a "best word" usually depends on the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=clear%20synonyms) suggests many, as well as a few of my own:

- [Clear](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=clear+meaning)
- [Comprehensible](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=comprehensible+meaning)
- Transparent (Although this is usually said as an insult to an individual who has a plan, so I wouldn't recommend it)
- [Distinct](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=+distinct)
- [Concise](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=concise)

Although these are all options, yours fits the bill just fine, if not a little formal. For a word in a casual conversation or chat<sup>1</sup> you might like to try:

> "Yeah, *I get you*"
>
> "It's all clear"

In summary, you've used the right word, but there are some good alternatives out there if you wish to use them!

---

<sup>1: Although that's not to say that "understood" would be completely inappropriate in a casual conversation!</sup>

### EDIT:

To express sympathy, you could (and should) use different terms to those that describe a knowledgeable understanding. If the person is going through a bad time:

- "I feel for you" (when the person is going through a bad time)
- "I know how you feel"

Or, if the person is judging their actions (or themselves) in response to their situation and circumstances:

- "You did the right thing"
- "It's not your fault"
- "You did the best you could"

Or, if you've been through a similar experience:

- "I've been there"
- "We've all been there" (if her situation is a common one)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

> "I understand."

It conveys personal contact, empathy, understanding, care.
Whereas...

> "You're being understood"

just emphasises the distance between you & the <strike>victim</strike> …err… subject.

Answer (score 1):

A possible suggestion: *clear* - You're being clear.

If you want to express **empathy** with the speaker (as opposed to a more intellectual understanding), you can say:

*I feel for you.*

> Feel for - sympathize with or feel sorry for someone (an idiom)

Comment: Unfortunately, clear is not necessarily a synonym to understandable. I can speak very clearly and express myself in a concise way - but you won't automatically understand what I'm saying. Especially in OPs example where he wants to express empathy.

Comment: "I can dig it"? :-)

Comment: I disagree with "Feel for". It implies an emotional connection, not one of intellectual understanding.

Comment: @Iplodman - I think the question could apply to either an intellectual or an emotional understanding, so I don't mind both options in an answer. That said, Darius – I don't think it's fair to edit the title of a question to fit your answer; instead, you should edit your answer to fit the question.